# How to receive notification of BigQuery Job errors

Tags: google-bigquery

When A BigQuery Job has an error, I can view the error in the Job history and StackDriver Logs.  I would like to be notified (by email) when any job fails.

In user preferences, I have enabled "StackDriver Error Reporting" for new errors.  I have also looked at the StackDriver BigQuery Resource to see if I could create an Alerting Policy, but I don't understand if any of the conditions apply to BQ job errors.

Is it possible and if so how can I receive notification of errors in BigQuery Jobs?

Comment: How are you running the query, is it through the API or some other means? [Scheduled queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) lets you specify an email address to notify if the query fails, which may be an option.

Comment: You can use BigQuery events for Google Cloud Functions - you might want to fill out this [signup form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfcnKD6Oak51o3I8a5-bwT9AeVp1V04ulSux_GR1lGn1hALrg/viewform) to gain access

Comment: I am using the node.js API `dataset.table(tableId).load(filePath)` in a cloud function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want an email for *every* BQ job error in your project, you could define a [log-based custom metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/) in Stackdriver. You would define it, thanks to filters on the content of the log, so that it counts the number of logs indicating an error on a BQ job. Then in Stackdriver Monitoring, you could define an alerting policy on this custom metric.

If you want to display the errors your jobs had in Error Reporting, you should add code to your Cloud Function so it reports the errors to Stackdriver when they happen, using the Error Reporting API. See [this link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/error-reporting) for more details on how. This means your Cloud Function would analyze the answer from the BQ API, and if it sees the job had an error, it reports it to Stackdriver.

Stackdriver Error Reporting apparently supports email notification, but only for the first occurence of an error. (And this feature is [in beta](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/notifications) it seems)

So if you want to receive emails for each failed BQ job triggered by the Cloud Function, I believe you should implement the logic of sending the email inside the Cloud Function.

Comment: I am unable to report from the results of my `.load()` call because the job submission is successful.  Its the job that fails.

Comment: I am able to use your first solution.  I created a user-defined metric on the BigQuery logs and then alert on that metric.  Thank you!